# Constants in a signature

Tags: logic, universal-algebra

This is my first post so I hope it works!
Taking the axioms for a group as an example, the literature defines
a group in (at least) two different ways:

Method 1

> A signature of $(G,\circ,\,^{-1})$ and axioms
>
> 1. Associativity. $g_{1}\circ(g_{2}\circ g_{3})=(g_{1}\circ g_{2})\circ g_{3}$.
> 2. Identity. $\exists e\in G,e\circ g=g$.
> 3. Inverse. $g^{-1}\circ g=e$.

Method 2

> A signature of $(G,\circ,\,^{-1},e)$ and axioms
>
> 1. Associativity. $g_{1}\circ(g_{2}\circ g_{3})=(g_{1}\circ g_{2})\circ g_{3}$.
> 2. Identity. $e\circ g=g$.
> 3. Inverse. $g^{-1}\circ g=e$.

The difference between the two is the definition of the constant $e$.

So is there any mathematical difference between these methods. I presume
that all theorems provable under method 1 are provable under method
2. Is that correct? If so, in general, is it the case that all constants
can be excluded from signatures and introduced with an existential
clause in an axiom?

Comment: Yes, the two are equivalent; in the first case, with axiom $\exists x (x \circ g=g)$ we prove the uniqueness of the "inverse", and thus we are licensed to expand the language with a new symbol: the *constant* $e$ such that: $e \circ g=g$.

Comment: There is also the variant where left and right versions of neutral element and inverse element are assumed in the axioms.

Comment: And yes; if the signature has a *constant* symbol $c$, we assume that it denotes something, i.e. the corresponding strucure $M$ has a "designated" element $c^m$ such that the symbol $c$ is its name. Otehrwise, as above, if we have an axiom asserting the existence (and uniqueness) of a certain objecet, we can add to the language a "name" for it.

Comment: Many thanks for your replies. I am not interested in group theory per se but in the general question of whether constants can be removed from a signature and replaced with existential clauses in the axioms.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in Kyle's answer, in the case you specifically asked about, it doesn't make much difference whether you include the *identity* element in your list of operations.

However, generally speaking, if you single out a special element of your universe and include it (as a constant, i.e. "nullary", operation) among your set of basic operations, it may turn out to have significant consequences for the equational theory of the algebra.  To see why, think about the set of equations you can write down which may or may not hold for this algebra.  This set may become larger if you give a name to some "special" element of the universe.

This is most strikingly illustrated in the 1982 paper [1] in which Roger Bryant proves that if you give a name to another element of a group, then the equational theory of the resulting algebra need not be generated by a finite set of equations.  In contrast, Oates and Powell in [2] proved that the equational theory of a finite group (without any specially named elements) is "finitely based".

...but let's not dwell on this deep equational stuff which can be very hard to make peace with.

On a much lighter note, there's another way to think about a nullary operation if you're a computer programmer---it's a *thunk*!  That is, it's an element of the universe that is posing as a function. This has important consequences for programming because it can determine when an expression will be evaluated.  (Functions and higher types are usually passed around using call-by-name, unlike primitive types which are usually passed call-by-value.)  Not sure how helpful it is to make that connection, but anyway I think it's kind of neat.

[1] “The laws of finite pointed groups” R. M. Bryant, Bull. London Math. Soc, 14 (1982), 119-123.

[2] “Identical relations in finite groups,” S. Oates, M. B. Powell, J. Algebra (1965).

Comment: Awesome answer! That actually sounds really neat!

Comment: @KyleGannon thanks, you too. I just learned about thunks recently, and they're useful in functional languages like Scala. You can delay evaluation of an input to a function by making the argument type, say, `() => Int` instead of just `Int`. In other words, you pass in a nullary function instead of an Int. Pretty cool, I think.

Comment: Very interesting answer, just the sort of thing I was looking for. Will try and get hold of those papers and settle down to a good read! Thanks.

Comment: There's a nice exposition of the Oates-Powell Theorem in Hanna Neumann's book "Varieties of Groups." [Here](https://github.com/williamdemeo/Isotopy/blob/master/pointedgroups.pdf?raw=true) is a link to the Bryant paper.

Comment: @DeMeo many thanks. Have been away for a while and have just picked this up. I was having problems finding the Bryant paper so the link helps a lot. Do you know of any model theory or universal algebra texts which treat this question generally and not in the context of group theory?

Answer (score 3):

If you consider *monoids* instead of groups, there will be a difference. The substructures of monoids with a distinguished identity are monoids, but without them they will usually be just plain semigroups. Consider, for example, the substructure of $\langle\mathbb{Z},+\rangle$ with universe the positive integers $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer prompts me to think that the normal rules for a substructure require inheritance of the signature. This may not happen with equational clauses as the substructure may have a different constant from the original.

Answer (score 2):

For practical purposes, no.

$(G,\circ, ^{-1},e)$ is a definable extension of $(G,\circ, ^{-1})$. You can defined the identity in $(G,\circ, ^{-1})$ via $\varphi(x) \equiv (\forall y)(y \circ x = x \circ y = y)$ and so for almost all intents and purposes, these structures/languages are the same.

(In general, one difference between a language and it's definable extensions can be quantifier elimination. For instance, $Th(\mathbb{R}, +, \times, 0,1)$ does not have Q.E. but the definable expansion $Th(\mathbb{R}, +, \times, 0,1,<)$ does)

Comment: Thanks, this is more to the point (see my comment above). I have heard of quantifier elimination but do not know about its ramifications. It was whether an existential clause would in general alter the theory if a constant was removed from the signature that interests me.

Comment: @coolbear: Could you be a little bit more specific about what you are asking for? Maybe an example of what you think might go wrong?